# How to implement php web service with FIFO queue

Tags: php, web-services

I got a web service implemented in php. When one user connect to the service, it return a some integers (ID numbers) and this numbers are never asigned again. 
The problem is that if two users connect to the web service in the same second, the first user request is not finished and the second user can receive the same numbers.
I want to delay second user execution till the end of the first user execution.

edit : add code from comment below

```
<?php // Get data 
    $param1 = $_GET['param1']; 
    $param2 = $_GET['param2']; 
    $param3 = $_GET['param3']; 
    // Create Number Manager 
    $numberManager = new NumberManager($param1); 
    // Get the Numbers 
    $numbers = $numberManager->getNumbers($param2, $param3); 
    // Print information on JSON format 
    $numbers->printJSON();
?>
```

Comment: Please provide some code you tried till now

Comment: Is not a code error, the problem is that the code execution is asynchronous for different users.

<?php

// Get data
$param1 = $_GET['param1'];
$param2 = $_GET['param2'];
$param3 = $_GET['param3'];

// Create Number Manager
$numberManager = new NumberManager($param1);

// Get the Numbers
$numbers = $numberManager->getNumbers($param2, $param3);

// Print information on JSON format
$numbers->printJSON();

?>

Comment: must they be numbers ? if uniqueness is what you are after, you could return `guid`'s instead ... (the probability of collision is small beyond ridiculous ... but not 0).